# i want to compare sql column with d1 variable in java

Tags: java, sql

```
try{
       Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
       int d1=21;

       int m1 = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
       int y1 = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       String db = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data1";
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(db,"root","");


       st=con.createStatement();
       String  sql ="SELECT id,name,d,m,y FROM Table5"
               + " WHERE d<d1";

          rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

        tb.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

          st.close();
          con.close();

} catch(Exception ex){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);        
}




String  sql ="SELECT id,name,d,m,y FROM Table5" + " WHERE d<d1";
```

computer show me d1 cannot compare with d

and d is my database column date and d1 is my computer date

Comment: "computer show me d1 cannot compare with d" No, your compiler gives a you a specific error message. [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27060849/edit) and put that error message in. And you also need to describe your Table5 structure. How can we now what types d and d1 are?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, then you have to do something like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT id,name,d,m,y FROM Table5 WHERE d < ?";
PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement(sql);
st.setInt(1, d1);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check what you have imported in your java class. there are two different dates.
java.sql.Date and java.util.Date. Better you can convert to same type or convert to seconds and compare...